# Creating a border using ncurses

Tags: c++, ascii-art, curses

The biggest question is if it's worth it to use a useless `if` statement to make the `x` and `y` variables local away from the main statement.

```
    //Unconventional part, make it so that x and y are local variables
if(true){
        int x,y;
        //set x and y to be the width + height of the terminal
        getmaxyx(stdscr,y,x);
        for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
                //top border
                mvaddch(0,i,'#');
                //bottom border
                mvaddch(y - 1,i,'#');
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < y; i++){
                //left border
                mvaddch(i,0,'#');
                //right border
                mvaddch(i,x - 1,'#');
        }
}
```

Comment: You could just have a block; the `if(true)` could be left out

Comment: @qxz, he wants to make x and y local variables. He asks if it's worth it. I would say that he should just make it a function.

Comment: @Incomputable I was just making a comment that you can have a plain block without the `if`. I agree that I'd make it a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a block without an `if` statement.
For example, these are equivalent:

```
{
    // some code
}

if (true) {
    // some code
}
```

But it's not a good practice to create blocks like this.
It's a *code smell*,
suggesting to wrap `// some code` in a dedicated function instead.

Anytime you think some neat trick is "unconventional",
it's most probably a bad practice. Don't do it, fix it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @janos said:

Your formatting style looks weird. This is because in `mvaddch(0,x - 1,'#')` there is plenty of space around the `-` operator, but none around the `,`. This commonly suggests that the `,` binds more tightly than the `-`, which is wrong.

So <s>either use no space at all or</s> use a space after the comma as well.